# Is 'window' always on top of the scope chain in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've seen global variables defined with window.global_name.
I wonder why not just using global_name even if this script will be run in closure.

**UPD**: seems like IE doesn't explicitly add it to the window object, when you declare it inside of a closure

Comment: Just to be anal, window is not always at the top of the scope chain in JavaScript. In a server side Node app for example, there's no window at all.

Comment: Event more anal then: only in DOM-scripting (that is: javascript within the Document Object Model, being the browser actually) window is on top of the scope chain. Javascript / Ecmascript can run in many (windowless) environments

Answer (score 2):

The last object on the scope chain in any ECMAScript environment is always the *global object*. In browsers, `window` is to all intents and purposes the global object. If you want to access a property of the global object `x` or a global variable `x` (which are almost but not quite the same thing), you should explicitly qualify it with `window.x` to avoid the possibility of `x` being resolved as a property of another object on the scope chain, or `globalObj.x` if you care about portability to non-browser environments. You can get a reference to the global object from anywhere in ECMAScript 3 or non-strict ECMAScript 5 as follows:

```
var globalObj = (function() { return this; })();
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.x` is safer than simply `x` if there might possibly be another `x` in the current or preceding scopes. That being said, even `window` isn't fool-proof because you could define a variable named `window`.

Comment: You can't redeclare `window`  in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: `function x() { var window = 10; alert(window); } x();` alerts `10` in FF4.

Comment: sorry, you're right; you can redeclare it in a more local scope.  However, you can't do so at global scope.

Answer (score 0):

They have similar effects, but `window` lets you explicitly declare that you're deliberately using a global.  Otherwise, the reader doesn't know whether it's a `var` further up the scope chain, you just forgot to declare it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you introduce another scope, e.g. by wrapping your code in a function, `window === this === <the global scope>`
However, `window` and `this` have the advantage that you can use the array syntax (`window['something']`) so you can access globals even if you have their name only in a string without using evil things like `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *yes*. If you declare a variable without the `var` keyword (inside a function), the variable will become implicitely a member of the `window` object, that is automatically initialized by the browser.

Outside a function, with or without the `var` keyword, the variable becomes implicitely a member of the `window` object.