# requirejs circular dependencies and function objects

Tags: javascript, requirejs, classloader, circular-dependency

Is it possible to differentiate between dependencies which are needed on structure build (like inheritance) and runtime dependencies (within a method call).

A little example:

2 "classes": Father and Child which depend on each other

**Father.js**

```
define(['Child'], function (Child) {

    function Father() {};    

    Father.prototype.childs = [];

    Father.prototype.addChild = function (c) {
        if (!(c instanceof Child)) {
            alert("nope");
        }
    }

    return Father;
});
```

**Child.js**

```
define(['Father'], function(Father){

   function Child(){
       this.father = [];
   }

   Child.prototype.setFather = function(f){
       if(!(f instanceof Father)){
           alert("false");
       }
   }

   return Child;
});
```

and an **app.js**

```
requirejs(['Child', 'Father'], function(Child, Father){
    var c = new Child();
    var f = new Father();
    c.setFather(f);
    f.addChild(c);
});
```

When using **export** you can only extend an object (if i'm correct). So is it possible to build a structure like this ?

**What i actually try to do**: have an automatic "class"-loading (seperated files), which loads all dependencies within a bigger model, which has some circular dependencies. Some dependencies needed right away (inheritance) and some are only needed after object initiation. And I cant find a nice solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (IMO) a vary valid question, puzzled me since yesterday. What I would consider if I were you, in preference order:

1. Embrace ducktyping. A useful `Child` class may have methods like `play()` and `cry()`, so the "if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck..." becomes "if it plays like child and cries like a child, then it is a child":

   ```
   // Father.js
   define([], function() {

       function Father() {};    

       Father.prototype.childs = [];

       Father.prototype.addChild = function (c) {
           if( !c || typeof(c.play) !== 'function' || typeof(c.cry) !== 'function' ) {
               alert("nope");
           }
       }

       return Father;
   });
   ```

   Another benefit of this approach (in the general case) is that you are actually programming against the equivalent of interfaces in Javascript. I.e. the thought process is *"What am I going to need a `Child` for? -Playing and crying. -Then it is enough for me that the object I get has these 2 methods. I do not care about the exact implementation of it."*
2. This is technical and ugly, but (at least IMO) acceptably ugly: You can introduce a 3rd dependency to break the cycle as is common with cycles. I.e.:

   ```
   // Father.js
   define([], function() {

       function Father() {};    

       Father.prototype.childs = [];

       return Father;
   });

   // Child.js
   define(['Father'], function(Father){

       function Child(){
           this.father = [];
       }

       Child.prototype.setFather = function(f){
           if(!(f instanceof Father)){
               alert("false");
           }
       }

       return Child;
   });

   // FatherAugmentor.js (any ideas for a better name?)
   define(['Father', 'Child'], function(Father, Child) {
       Father.prototype.addChild = function (c) {
           if (!(c instanceof Child)) {
               alert("nope");
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   **A catch:** you must make sure that the `FatherAugmentor` is required from somewhere! Alternatively, you can play with names (ugly again), so that the `FatherAugmentor` from above becomes the `Father` and the `Father` from above is renamed to, e.g. `FatherBase`:

   ```
   // FatherBase.js
   define([], function() {
       // exactly the same as `Father.js` from above
   });

   // Child.js
   define(['FatherBase'], function(Father){
       // exactly the same as `Child.js` from above
   });

   // Father.js
   define(['FatherBase', 'Child'], function(Father, Child) {
       // exactly the same as `FatherAugmentor.js` from above
   });
   ```

   With this you make sure that anybody that requests the `Father`
   will get the full class, but you have to be careful to use the `FatherBase` in the files that are parts of the cycle (i.e. `Child.js` and `Father.js`).
3. One could consider solutions involving a namespace object (i.e. return a `family` object that contains the constructors as `family.Father` and `family.Child`), but I think it gets too ugly.

Comment: those alternatives are nice and properly should be considered on a big refactor. I only need it in a dev enviroment, the code will be generated into a diffrent structure for the productive system. I made a little nastier solution

Answer (score -1):

I know this is not a very nice and properly breaks some optimization and some convention (like handling modules with the same name). So here is a solution wich copies all the modules in the global scope.

**Child.js**

```
define(['Father'], function(){

//   var Father = require("Father");
   function Child(){
       this.father = [];
   }

   Child.prototype.setFather = function(f){
       if(!(f instanceof Father)){
           alert("false");
       }
   }

   window.Child = Child;
});
```

**Father.js**

```
define(['Child'], function () {

    function Father() {};    

    Father.prototype.childs = [];

    Father.prototype.addChild = function (c) {
        if (!(c instanceof Child)) {
            alert("nope");
        }
    };

    window.Father = Father;
});
```

**app.js**

```
requirejs(['Child', 'Father'], function(){
    var c = new Child();
    var f = new Father();
    c.setFather(f);
    f.addChild(c);
    console.log("done");
});
```

To sync the loading (on a more complex project) i use a mediator which keeps track of needed loading and which fires an event when everything is loaded.

instead of window you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/5573049/228763 to work with on other platforms.